# How to ask for showing Youtube links that are in foreign language meant for beginners?

Tags: discussion, support

I have discovered some really good videos in Youtube  that would help beginner's questions concerning note reading, chords, staff etc.such I have encountered here in the last  few weeks  I've been in this SE group.

The point is that they are in German and maybe many users don't know how to google as they lack the musical terms and also the search techniques.

The following video actually is so fantastic and I wonder whether all of you know how it can be translated in English on Youtube.

He is speaking about holistic piano learning.

I'll try once in the beta, let's see what happens.

Comment: To answer your basic question, "how to ask for showing YouTube links," 

Please don't. That sort of question is off topic and will be closed.

Comment: My question was wrong formulated: I meant to ask for a beginner: how do I find the translation of a good video. I was thinking of one like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yey-tUmc-YE&t=43s

It would be very complicated to translate this. What I meant is how to show beginners that they can look up at the subtitles and their translation.
This was my attention - instead of explaining with long words - that probably never will be read. As we say a picture shows more than a thousand words this will also be true for a video.

Comment: That is even more off topic here, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

In some ways, the language of the video doesn't matter. Answers on the main site should be self-contained. That is, if you read the text of the answer but don't follow any of the links, that should be enough to know the answer to the question. Any videos or other links in the answer should just be to illustrate it with examples.

If you think of it in that way, if the example in an answer is a video, it doesn't matter what people **say** in the video, because the music is the important part. Whatever is said in the video should already be covered by the text in the answer. In that case, it doesn't matter if the people in the video speak German or any other language, because you don't need to understand what they say to understand the answer.

Any answer where the *content* of the answer is on the other side of a link, or you can't understand the answer at all without watching the video, may be flagged and deleted as a "link-only answer". The purpose of this site isn't to make a collection of links like a search engine, it's to make a collection of *genuine questions* and answers. If your aim is to make the videos easier to find or more accessible, this isn't the place to do that. Instead, you might make a post on your blog or on a forum for beginning musicians.